# open view in New Window From Controller Code not From Link or Button

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

How Can I Return or open a view in new window browser from only controller code when some validation a true **But Not from Links and button code**  it should open automatically  modelstate  if is valid. 
Thanks...

Comment: Please rephrase this question. It's doesn't appear entirely clear. Try to locate a native speaker who might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess at what you are trying to do is have the browser pop up a window once the form is correctly validated.  The way I would do this is to have a javascript function that is validating the form and once it is valid then pop up the new window.

If you want the validation to occur on the server side you could use AJAX to post the current form values back to the server and have it return the validation.